# Apache mod_rewrite change domain extension

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I want to have a 4 conditional mod_rewrite.

```
http to https
http://example.com to https://example.com

www. to non-www.
https://www.example.com to https://example.com

non-plural ending to plural ending domain
https://www.example.com to https://examples.com

.com (or that is not .co) domain extension to .co
https://www.example.com to https://examples.co
```

I so far have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.co%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

I am having trouble finding an example to create change **example** to **examples** and **.com** (or other non-.co) to **.co**.

Can I add to the above code or do I need to create another RewriteRule as well?

Note, I want to maintain all subdomains (except www.) also if someone writes www.subdomain.example.com, I want to keep the subdomain to but remove leading www. and change example.com to examples.co.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your additional "note" at the end regarding subdomains is really the main complication here.

So, the canonical domain is `examples.co`. Any request for anything other than the canonical domain needs to be redirected to the canonical domain.

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and remove any www subdomain and trailing dot (FQDN)
# NB: Potentially includes a subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

# Canonicalise the hostname "examples.co" and retain an optional subdomain
# NB: The www (sub)subdomain has already been removed.
#     Potentially includes a subdomain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !examples\.co$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.)?examples?\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1examples.co%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

The first rule primarily strips the optional www subdomain (or sub-subdomain). The `%1` backreference contains the hostname less the www subdomain (if any) and less any trailing dot (a FQDN) - as captured by the *CondPattern* `^(?:www\.)?(.+?)\.?$`.

The second rule canonicalises the domain name. Any optional subdomain is captured (in the `%1` backreference) and everything after this is ignored. We already know that the requested hostname does not end in `examples.co` (by the first *condition*).

This will result in at most 2 redirects. The second redirect occurs when a non-canonical domain is requested.

For example:

- Request `http://www.examples.co/foo` => `https://examples.co/foo`.
- Request `http://www.example.com/foo` => `https://example.com/foo` => `https://examples.co/foo`.
- Request `http://www.subdomain.example.com/` => `https://subdomain.example.com/` => `https://subdomain.examples.co/`.

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues. Only change to a 301 when you have confirmed that it's working OK. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

This does assume you are not implementing [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). If you are then you will need to redirect HTTP to HTTPS first on the same host.

Just to note, if you are using standard *wildcard* subdomains (as suggested in your [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/954011/https-security-warning-for-sub-subdomains)) then a request for `https://www.<subdomain>.<domain>` will likely get stopped by the browser (and consequently no redirect will occur), since the SSL cert won't be valid.

Comment: Awesome answer. I have one problem, this is resulting in a example.co//path-to-something with two slashes

Comment: Is that `example.co` with no `s`? What is the URL being requested that results in such a redirect? The double slash can't be _caused_ by these directives alone - unless perhaps there is a conflict with existing directives? Do you have other directives? In what context are these directives? _server_, _virtualhost_, `<Directory>` or `.htaccess`?